# datastax spark java heap space error

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

Im trying to execute small calculation using scala. Im using datastax-4.6.
I have 6-nodes each of 16gb RAM and 8-cores. When i try to exexute the scala program it displays the follwing error.

**ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**. I have alloctaed 2-cores for each machine and executor memory is 4gb and driver memory is 4gb. Any suggestions??.

Answer (score 1):

Directly quoting [Russ's article on Common Spark Troubleshooting](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/common-spark-troubleshooting) (you should read it!):

> Spark Executor OOM:
>
> How to set Memory Parameters on Spark Once a app
>   is running the next most likely error you will see is an OOM on a
>   spark executor. Spark is an extremely powerful tool for doing
>   in-memory computation but it’s power comes with some sharp edges. The
>   most common cause for an executor OOM’ing is that the application is
>   trying to cache or load too much information into memory. Depending on
>   your use case there are several solutions to this:
>
> 1) Increase the parallelism of your job. Try increasing the number of
>   partitions in your job. By splitting the work into smaller sets of
>   data less information will have to be resident in memory at a given
>   time. For a Spark Cassandra Connector job this would mean decreasing
>   the split size variable. The variable,
>   spark.cassandra.input.split.size, can be set either on the command
>   line as above or in the SparkConf object. 
>   For other RDD types look
>   into their api’s to determine exactly how they determine partition
>   size.
>
> 2) Increase the storage fraction variable,
>   spark.storage.memoryFraction. This can be set as above on either the
>   command line or in the SparkConf object. This variable sets exactly
>   how much of the JVM will be dedicated to the caching and storage of
>   RDD’s. You can set it as a value between 0 and 1, describing what
>   portion of executor JVM memory will be dedicated for caching RDDs. If
>   you have a job that will require very little shuffle memory but will
>   utilize a lot of cached RDD’s increase this variable (example: Caching
>   an RDD then performing aggregates on it.)
>
> 3) If all else fails you may
>   just need additional ram on each worker. For DSE users adjust your
>   spark-env.sh (or dse.yaml file in DSE 4.6) file to increase SPARK_MEM
>   reserved for Spark jobs. You will need to restart your workers for
>   these new memory limits to take effect (dse sparkworker restart.) Then
>   increase the amount of ram the application requests by setting
>   spark.executor.memory variable either on the command line or in the
>   SparkConf object.

Comment: Hi Phact, thanks for the reply. Im new to cassandra and can you please guide me how to setup the 1 and 2 options. I have fiund spark.executor.memory option in spark-env.sh file but not the other two. I would be thankful if u guide me to solve my problem.